# Find the topic of a query

Tags: facebook

Given a question, say like, what is current or what is a mouse... Is it possible to know which topic this question belongs to?
I am trying to write an app, that will scan through a user's friends list(on facebook, twitter, g+..., hope fully not more than 2 levels) and for a given question try to find a person who may be able to provide an answer.

To do that, the question and the topic of the question needs to be found. If there is a service provider who could do similar service, that too would be a good starter.

I would like to tag this question better. Could someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Hope I have found an answer right here...
Stack exchange api list is a good starter. Of course some more analysis over the response will be required, but to start with this is a good one, as far as what I have read. Let me try that now.